# Dropbox web service API returns content must be application/json

Tags: c#, json, dropbox-api

I'm trying to gather some data from Dropbox however finding that the service is returning a message that the request isn't in the correct format.

I can successfully retrieve data from the service using a call which doesn't require JSON however when I try making a call which includes JSON the service replies it's not in the correct format.

I'm using PostAsJsonAsync method in the HttpClient class.

```
response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("/1/team/members/list", "{ \"limit\" : 100 }");
json = System.Web.Helpers.Json.Decode(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
```

The service responds:

> error = "Content-Type must be \"application/json\". Got
>   application/json; charset=utf-8"

Comment: This constraint has been relaxed, so "application/json; charset=utf-8" should work now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, you'll need to set the `Content-Type` header to exactly `application/json`. I suspect we'll be able to relax the constraint in the future so `application/json; charset=utf-8` will also work.

Here's a similar question on Microsoft's forums (but no helpful answer): http://forums.asp.net/t/1982431.aspx?How+to+remove+charset+utf8+from+Content+Type+header+generated+by+HttpClient+PostAsJsonAsync+. I'd suggest just using a different method which allows you to set the `Content-Type` header explicitly.